# Javascript, consolidate array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck of finding a way to consolidate array elements.

so my array is in format of **[id1:port1,id2:port2,id1:port3,id2:port4,id5:port5...]** where each element has 2 portions. The id portion is not unique. what I try to consolidate is to create a new array will have data like **[id1#port1:port3,id2#port2:port4,id5#port5]**

I tried code below but it didn't get me too far. can any guru help me out?

```js
var orinString = "id1:port1,id2:port2,id1:port3,id2:port4,id5:port5";

var newArray1 = orinString.split(",");
var newArray2 = orinString.split(",");
var newArray3 = [];

for (x=0; x<=newArray1.length-1; x++) {
  for (y=0; y<= newArray2.length-1; y++) {
    if ((newArray1[x].split(":")[0] == newArray2[y].split(":")[0]) && (newArray1[x].split(":")[1] != newArray2[y].split(":")[1])) {
      newArray3.push(newArray1[x].split(":")[0] +"#"+ newArray1[x].split(":")[1]);
    }
  }
}

for (z=0; z<=newArray3.length; z++) {
  gs.log("show me the result " +newArray3[z]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "consolidate"?

Comment: maybe I should use word manipulate, sorry I really don't know the proper term but what I want to get from raw format of [id1:port1,id2:port2,id1:port3,id2:port4,id5:port5...]  to [id1#port1:port3,id2#port2:port4,id5#port5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it that you want:

```
var orinString = "id1:port1,id2:port2,id1:port3,id2:port4,id5:port5";
var arr1 = orinString.split(",");
var temp= ""; 
var newStr = "";
arr1.sort();
for(i=0; i< arr1.length; i++) {
    var item = arr1[i].split(':');
    if(item[0] !== temp || temp === "") {
        newStr += "," + item[0] + "#" + item[1];
    } else {
        newStr += ":"+item[1];
    }
    temp = item[0];
}
console.log(newStr.substring(1));
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to solve a problem like this is

- Convert them into workable values
- Populate some kind of lookup table
- Output the results of this lookup table

For example

```
var orinString = "id1:port1,id2:port2,id1:port3,id2:port4,id5:port5";

var idsAndPorts = orinString.split(",");

// Populate a key lookup
var hashTable = {};
idsAndPorts.forEach(function(s) {
  var splitValue = s.split(':');
  var key = splitValue[0];
  var value = splitValue[1];
  if(hashTable[key]) {
    hashTable[key].push(value);
  } else {
    hashTable[key] = [value];
  }
});

// Now convert it back into an array again
var finalArray = [];
for(var k in hashTable) {
  finalArray.push(k + '#' + hashTable[k].join(','));
}

// View the results
finalArray.forEach(function(f) {
  console.log(f);
})
```

This does not guarantee the final array will be sorted, but you can sort it yourself if you wish.